# Php run multiple processes (MAMP)

Tags: php, macos, parallel-processing, mamp, mamp-pro

My problem is: I would like to run more than 6 processes parallely (tabs in Chrome or Safari) that using localhost's MAMP php engine. (Big, long-term queries, parsing several xml from the web).

When I open the 7th tab and navigate to a localhost/php script page it begins to wait till one of my 6 another processes ends. I don't really know how to set anything to allow it. What controls the processes? MAMP? Apache? PHP-ini inside? Something else?

Any help is appreciated.

- OS X 10.9.5
- MAMP Pro 3.0.5 (php 5.5.10)

Comment: Why are you running something like this on tabs? Surely it would better be suited for the command line?

Comment: It is better for me to view the result :) And I can immediately visualize the result while I put the result in a csv.